# 22.10 and nvidia 525

Tags: nvidia, 22.10

On my ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X756UV with a nvidia GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
it seem  nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free recommended is not functional.
From the distro-upgrade (from 22.04) it boot in console mode and startx crash, back in "Software Rendering" graphics i try to add the driver from "additional driver" from update manager box and that crash as well.

Comment: So is your question how to install another driver that works? As of now, there is no explicit question.